# CellIdentityGSM & CellInfoGsm

Tags: java, android

I wanna know how to use the CellIdentityGsm & CellInfoGsm.
I have tried many methods, but didn't work, the latest code I tried is:

```
List <CellInfo> cellInfo1 = (List<CellInfo>) tm.getAllCellInfo();
for (CellInfo cellInfo2 : cellInfo1) {
    CellInfoGsm cellInfoGsm1 = (CellInfoGsm) cellInfo2;
    CellIdentityGsm cellIdentityGsm1 = cellInfoGsm1.getCellIdentity();

    int Mcc = cellIdentityGsm1.getMcc();
    view = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.mCC);
    view.setText("MCC: " + Mcc);
}
```

Comment: My source for this kind of very general information is usually the Android documentation. 
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/package-summary.html

Comment: How to use it for what?  What are you trying to do?

Comment: @Tom That was unintentionally. It must have been a slip of the copy-paste fingers. Good that you fixed it.